# Bulma navbar and VueJS router active link

Tags: vuejs2, bulma

I've started using **Bulma 0.7.1** and **VueJs 2.5.17**. Now, I'm using Vue router component and I'd like to make the buttons in the navigation bar to be set as active whenever I'm on the "page" represented by the link.

My code is the following

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation" id="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="navMenu" class="navbar-menu">
                    <div class="navbar-end">
                        <a class="navbar-item is-active">
                            <router-link to="/" exact>Home</router-link>
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                            <router-link to="/about" exact>About</router-link>
                        </a>
                        <a class="navbar-item">
                            <router-link to="/project" exact>Project</router-link>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-end">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <router-view/>

    </div>
</template>
```

I know that router component uses class `router-link-active` to mark the active link. But Bulma probably requires the `is-active` class applied to the current button.

How should I automate this? I've read that probably I should bind the class `is-active` to the `router-link-active`, but I tried:

```
let routes = ...

new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes,
  linkActiveClass: "is-active"
});
```

And did not worked.

Any hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track and are right, 'is-active' is the answer. In router add.

```
export const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
    linkActiveClass: 'is-active'
})
```

And construct your HTML like.

```
<nav class="navbar is-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navMenu"
                 class="navbar-menu">
                <div class="navbar-start">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'templateInfo' }"
                                 class="navbar-item">Template info</router-link>
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'thirdpartylibraries' }"
                                 class="navbar-item">Third party libraries</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This works for me so I guess there's some issue with the order of your div's or classes.

Comment: It works well and refines the code by removing unnecessary tags. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Bulma Guide](https://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/syntax/), `is-active` is one modifier, you have to use it together with bulma element.

> Most Bulma elements have alternative styles. To apply them, you only
>   need to append one of the modifier classes. **They all start with** `is-` or
>   `has-`.

So change the configuration to like `linkActiveClass: 'tag is-active'` it will work well.

Like below demo which uses `tag` (you can choose others like `box`, `button` etc):

```js
let UserView = Vue.component('user', {
  template: '<div>I am User</div>'
})

let AdminView = Vue.component('admin', {
  template: '<div>I am Admin</div>'
})

const router = new VueRouter({
  linkActiveClass: 'tag is-active',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/Admin',
      name: 'Admin',
      component: AdminView
    },
    {
      path: '/User',
      name: 'User',
      component: UserView
    }
  ]
})
Vue.use(VueRouter)
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router
})
```

```css
.loading {
  background-color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>Test Vue Router</h2>
    <router-link to="Admin">Admin</router-link>
    <router-link to="User">User</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to see Bulma CSS classes in the example, but I can't. Am I missing something?

Comment: you are saying the example in my answer? the css classes is in the javascript codes which create Vue router instance.